# Is there any estimation on the number of Lightning Network payment?

Tags: lightning-network, adoption

Everyone knows that LN helps scale Bitcoin by moving most of the micro-payment transactions off-chain. But what really happens in real life? How many payments have been made per month?

Appreciate any pointer, or even statistics from folks running an LN node.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the answer will not be satisfying for you as by the end of the day the number can at best be estimated.

I have a very inactive node but [released a video at some point about the forwordings that my node has conducted](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MZKc58F2mTw). There are more people on twitter always dropping some numbers (eg [here](https://twitter.com/paoloardoino/status/1496409297097572358) or [there](https://twitter.com/bitrefill/status/1501246846374666242)).

I guess the best what you can do is to understand that [the centrality of your node on the graph might be proportional to the fraction of all payments that you will have observed](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L39IvFqTZk8). From that you can extrapolate the full number. however that observation makes the crucial but most likely wrong assumption that all payment pairs are equally likely.